# How to check which activity finished

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume

In my Android application I need to Override the onResume() method to check which of two possible activities just finished.  The user will either have entered an amount of money, or named and chosen a percent for a category.  How can I do that?  Also, if a user presses home and then goes back to my app, is onResume() called?  If so, I can just call super.onResume(), right?

I have three classes: PaySaver, NewSavingCategory, and NewPaycheck.  PaySaver.java is the main Activity, and there are two buttons: New Paycheck (launches a dialog box where a user inputs $ (NewPaycheck.java)) and New Saving Category (launches a dialogbox where a user inputs a name and a % (NewSavingCategory.java)).  When the dialog box is closed via an enter button, I want the main activity to be updated with the information entered.

Thanks!

Comment: Two questions! I use the first one: Can you please go into detail before we can answer. What part of your app did start these activities. Most of the time you start activities with startActivity or startActivityForResult. If you come back from the second one the calling activity with receive an onActivityResult callback. Here you can check what activty ended and query its result.

Comment: I have three classes: PaySaver, NewSavingCategory, and NewPaycheck.  PaySaver.java is the main Activity, and there are two buttons: New Paycheck (launches a dialog box where a user inputs $ (NewPaycheck.java)) and New Saving Category (launches a dialogbox where a user inputs a name and a % (NewSavingCategory.java)).  When the dialog box is closed via an enter button, I want the main activity to be updated with the information entered.

Comment: I used the startActivityForResult, it worked perfectly!  Exactly what I needed!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I do that?

Most likely, you don't. Both of those other activities updated your central data model. In `onResume()`, you update your UI from that same central data model. Hence, it does not matter where the user came from -- you are grabbing the latest data.

> Also, if a user presses home and then goes back to my app, is onResume() called?

On the activity they return to, yes.

> If so, I can just call super.onResume(), right?

Not only "can" you do that, you *have* to call `super.onResume()`, or your activity will crash.